# Updating entity data to Azure storage table

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I have a scenario where I insert/update data to Azure storage table 2 values MyValue and MyDate.

There are few scenarios where I have to update only 1 value MyValue and not MyDate.

But When I do update operation, it updates bothe the values. It changes myValue but makes MyDate to null.

Is there any operation in update where I can skip MyDate update and keep its value as it is?

```
public class MyEntity : TableEntity
{
public MyEntity(string partitionKey, string rowKey) : 
 base(partitionKey, rowKey)
 {
 }
public string MyValue { get; set; }
public DateTime MyTime { get; set; }
}
```

This code insert or replaces data

```
   var entity = new MyEntity(partitionKey, rowKey)
     {
        MyValue = "test my value",
        MyTime = DateTime.Now();
     };

    AddEntity(entity);



     public void AddEntity(MyEntity entity)
     {
     CloudTable table =     _tableClient.GetTableReference("myAzureStorageTableName");
 TableOperation insertOp = TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(entity);
 table.Execute(insertOp);                         
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage Merge operation. Please note that you should set ETag to "*" if you don't want to read the entity before updating it.

References:

1. [Merge Entity REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179392.aspx)
2. [TableOperation.Merge Method in .NET library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.tableoperation.merge?view=azure-dotnet)

Comment: Link #2 is broken

Answer (score 3):

Here Both `InsertOrMerge` and `Merge` operation are ok.